# How to show product attribute options product page in Magento?

Tags: attributes

I am using an attribute to show an attribute value in the product page using this code:

```
<?php if ($_product->getProductShipping()):?>
    <p>Shipping Charges : Rs.<?php echo $_product->getProductShipping(); ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

It is showing *Shipping Charges : Rs. 20*. What is the value of this attribute? If some products have no value in this product then nothing is showing there but I want to show *Free shipping* if no value is there.

Comment: hello any one reply?

Comment: don't mind, But I am going through your profile and see there are many question which are answered and work for you too. but neither vote up nor accept them. 
I think you should do these things to encourage users to answer to your problems.

Comment: Literally saying "Give me the code" does not inspire people to help you either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just simple `if/else` condition can do work for you

```
<?php if ($_product->getProductShipping()){?>
    <p>Shipping Charges : Rs.<?php echo $_product->getProductShipping(); ?>
<?php }else { ?>
    <p>Shipping Charges : Free Shipping
<?php } ?>
```

let me know if you face any problem in this code.

Comment: @NirupamArya  if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.